# How to access es-2015 class methods on its instance?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

For example I have

```
class MyClass {

  constructor() {
    this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
    // ... some more code
    // return what?
  }

  myMethod() {
   this.myMethod2();
   // do stuff ...
  }

  myMethod2() {
    // do stuff 2 ...
  }
}
```

Then I will do something like this

```
let obj = new MyClass();
```

And what I want to do is to access `myMethod` from the `obj`

```
obj.myMethod();
```

Obviously, if `myMethod` calls other `MyClass` methods in its code (like `myMethod2`), I want everything to work as expected. So I assume that constructor should return some sort of object and include its public methods (which can access object's private methods), but how to do it?

Comment: I would recommend reading a good document on ES6 Classes. Perhaps [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?

Comment: ES6 classes don't have private methods, although they can be created by declaring them as inner functions of the constructor but can then only be referenced from other functions also declared within the constructor.   Your constructor doesn't need to return anything, because it implicitly returns `this`.

Comment: You should try your code, it's working.

Comment: What I meant under 'private method' - is a method that should not be called from the outside of the class.

Comment: @Mihail "should not", or "cannot" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way (that I know of) to have private methods in ES6 classes is to define them as inner functions of the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        let privateVar = 'foo';
        let privateMethod = () => {
            return privateVar;
        }
    }
}
```

Any method defined outside of the constructor is implicitly public.

The only public methods that can access the private variables or methods are ones similarly defined within the lexical scope of the constructor and attached to the current instance as properties of `this`:

```
constructor() {
    let privateVar = 'foo';
    let privateMethod = () => {
        return privateVar;
    }
    this.publicMethod = () => {
        return privateMethod();
    }
}
```

(Note that the use of arrow functions means that `this` inside `this.publicMethod` will always point to the current instance without any need for a `.bind` call)